# null reference exception on page redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm getting a null reference exception on singleKingButton.Checked = true; in the page load event. If I comment it out then I still get one on the next line setting the date. The odd thing is the page loads fine it's when I hit the submit button that I get the error. Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace garrettPenfieldUnit4
{

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Reservation newReservation = new Reservation();
        //Load events, automatically inserts todays date and selects the single king radio button
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
                singleKingButton.Checked = true;
                arrivalDateBox.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
            }

            //When submit button is clicked show the two confirmation labels.
            protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            newReservation.ArrivalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(arrivalDateBox.Text);
            newReservation.DepartureDate = Convert.ToDateTime(departureDateBox.Text);
            newReservation.NoOfPeople = peopleDropDown.SelectedIndex;
            newReservation.SpecialRequests = specialRequestsBox.Text;
            newReservation.FirstName = firstNameBox.Text;
            newReservation.LastName = lastNameBox.Text;
            newReservation.Email = addressBox.Text;
            newReservation.Phone = telephoneNumberBox.Text;
            newReservation.PreferredMethod = contactDropDown.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            if (singleKingButton.Checked)
            {
                newReservation.BedType = "Single King";
            }

            if (twoQueensButton.Checked)
            {
                newReservation.BedType = "Two Queens";
            }

            if (singleQueenButton.Checked)
            {
                newReservation.BedType = "Single Queen";
            }
            Session["Reservation"] = newReservation;
            Response.Redirect("~/ConfirmationPage.aspx");
        }

            //When the clear button is clicked clear the form and reset fields to their default values
            protected void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                arrivalDateBox.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
                departureDateBox.Text = String.Empty;
                peopleDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
                singleKingButton.Checked = true;
                twoQueensButton.Checked = false;
                singleQueenButton.Checked = false;
                specialRequestsBox.Text = String.Empty;
                firstNameBox.Text = String.Empty;
                lastNameBox.Text = String.Empty;
                addressBox.Text = String.Empty;
                telephoneNumberBox.Text = String.Empty;
                contactDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
    }

}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="garrettPenfieldUnit4.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Royal Inn and Suites</title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="submitButton" defaultfocus="arrivalDateBox">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="page-header">
                <h1 style="color: blue;">Royal Inn and Suites</h1>
                <p style="color: red; font-style: italic;">
                Where you're always treated like royalty
            </div>
            <h3 style="color: blue;">Reservation Request</h3>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
        </div>
        <div id="form-group">
            <h4>Request Data</h4>
            <div>
                Arrival Date<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="arrivalDateBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Arrival date is required"
                    ControlToValidate="arrivalDateBox" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="arrivalDateValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Arrival date must be before departure date."
                    ControlToValidate="arrivalDateBox" ControlToCompare="departureDateBox" Display="Dynamic"
                    Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ForeColor="red">*</asp:CompareValidator>
            </div>

            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="arrivalDateBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>Departure Date</div>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="departureDateBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="departureDateBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Departure date is required"
                    ControlToValidate="departureDateBox" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="departureDateCompareValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Departure date must be after arrival date"
                    ControlToValidate="departureDateBox" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="arrivalDateBox" Display="Dynamic" Operator="GreaterThan"
                    Type="Date">*</asp:CompareValidator>
            </div>
            <div>Number of People</div>

            <div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="peopleDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    Bed Type
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="singleKingButton" runat="server" Text="King" GroupName="bedType" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="twoQueensButton" runat="server" Text="Two Queens" GroupName="bedType" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="singleQueenButton" runat="server" Text="Single Queen" GroupName="bedType" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <h3>Special Requests</h3>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="specialRequestsBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>

            <h3>Contact Information</h3>
            <div>First Name</div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="firstNameBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="firstNameBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="First name is required"
                ControlToValidate="firstNameBox" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <div>Last Name</div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="lastNameBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="lastNameBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Last name is required"
                ControlToValidate="lastNameBox" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <div>E-mail Address</div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="addressBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="addressBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email address is required"
                ControlToValidate="addressBox" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="addressBoxExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email"
                ControlToValidate="addressBox" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <div>Telephone Number</div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="telephoneNumberBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="telephoneNumberBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Telephone Number is required"
                ControlToValidate="telephoneNumberBox" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="telephoneExpressionValidator" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Invalid phone number" ControlToValidate="telephoneNumberBox" ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <div>Preferred Method of Contact</div>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="contactDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                <asp:ListItem>E-mail</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Telephone</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-space" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="clearButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-space" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="clearButton_Click" BackColor="#33CC33" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="submitLabel1" runat="server" Text="Thank you for your Request." Visible="False" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="submitLabel2" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Text="We will get back to you within 24 hours." Visible="False" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are those controls declared on your page? Are you removing them in any way?

Comment: Yes and no. (I'm assuming your referring to the current page and not the page it is redirected to when the button is clicked) I added the html code as well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of these all properties is receiving 'NULL' and at the time of inserting this values in database your table structure is not allowing 'NULL'.

So make sure that if you want to store 'NULL' in table then allow NULL in table structure (Table design).

You can check it using "line by line execution" of your code (using break point).